# mPDF: long text in table td shrinks to small size

Tags: mpdf

I am posting an entire html to mpdfp. It works fine. But when the content in table is more or there is an email address or website name in the column (td) the font size of the text shrinks to unreadable font. What must be the issue? Please help on this. Check the attached image for the issue.

[image: Please check the attached image for the issue]Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As noted in this question: [mPDF: Text becomes small when string in table is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825631/text-becomes-small-when-string-is-too-large-in-mpdf/)

mPDF automatically reduces font size in tables. There is a maximum shrink factor set in `$this->shrink_tables_to_fit` variable in `config.php`. It can be turned off / set differently with

```
$mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit=0;
```

in `config.php` or with providing an extra parameter to the opening table tag:

```
<table autosize="1">
```

Default value for the variable is 1.4.

Also see Tables section of mPDF manual https://mpdf.github.io/tables/tables.html#autosize, especially the infobox *Note: mPDF will always resize tables if it is the only way to fit a row or whole table onto a full page.*

Comment: Didn't work for me, my table still shows microscopic size text.

Comment: It does not work for me ($mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit=0; and autosize="1" in table)

Comment: @KowsiganAtsayam To what? If you have a problem not solved with this answer, create a separate SO Question. Also note the infobox in the docs: "_Note: mPDF will always resize tables if it is the only way to fit a row or whole table onto a full page._"